# VBA Excel: How to assign values to empty slots in an array through a function

Tags: arrays, excel, vba

Currently I'm working on a little interpolation code (Newton's Divided Difference). Problem is I'm having trouble assigning the table values that I've calculated in a function to my initial array that has the f(x) values. I keep getting the error **"Can't assign to array"**. Any help would be greatly appreciated

Here is a little snippet of the code in question and how I declared the variables

```
'Dim our variables, arrays
`Dim n, i, order As Integer
Dim x(9), y(9, 9), xi As Double

n = 9

'select our x data

For i = 0 To n
    x(i) = Worksheets("Newton").Range("B" & i + 4)
Next

'select our y data

For i = 0 To n
    y(i, 0) = Worksheets("Newton").Range("D" & i + 4)
Next


'select the value at which we want to interpolate
xi = Range("E1")

'This is where the problem is
y = divided_Table(x, y, n)

'Message the output
MsgBox "The estimate of f(x) is " & applyNewton(xi, x, y, n)


End Sub

Function divided_Table(x, y, n)
Dim i, j As Integer
    For i = 1 To n
        For j = 0 To n - i
            y(j, i) = ((y(j, i - 1) - y(j + 1, i - 1)) / (x(j) - x(i + j)))

            Next j
        Next i

End Function
```

Comment: Try using a different name than `y`, e.g. `why=divided_Table(x,y,n)`

Comment: Is there no way to add it all into y, because that would make sorting through the data a lot easier.

Comment: don't think so, since you define y as an array in the beginning, that's why you get the error.

Comment: @nonGMO Please edit some example data and expected output to your question.

Answer (score 0):

Would be nice to know at which line you get the error. But here are two items you may not know...

When you say:

`Dim x(9), y(9, 9), xi As Double`

the system will dim `x()` and `y()` as variants and NOT as doubles. The `xi` will be a double.

And if you dim  `x(9)`  the array does not have 9 slots - it has 10 (0-9).

Can't say that either of these items is your problem, but it is still good to be in the know.